Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config') when importing CSS in Next.js with PostCSS and CSS Loader
./src/styles/font.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[3]!./src/styles/font.css
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
i tried changing config files and verifying but not getting results

Can we please get a [mcve]?
